# How to fix: 'Error in strwidth' when plotting legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I am trying to plot a line chart with points with a legend based on the colour of the points. The chart plots correctly but the legend does not display.

The data behind the chart is a format of a dataframe with 4 columns - Month, variable (e.g. specific users), value (a numeric value representing a score) and colour (a red/amber/green value based on the numeric score).

The chart code is as follows:

```
ggplot(data = meltdf2, aes(x = Month, y = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(colour = meltdf2$colour, size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month" , date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "darkgrey"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

legend("topleft", legend = c("High", "Mid", "Low"), pch = 1,  col= c("red2","gold","limegreen"))
```

Regardless of whether I run the plot and legend code separately or together and if I include them in the same paraentheses or not, I get the error: 
`Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet`

Any advice on how to get the legend to display would be much appreciated.

Comment: `legend` and `strwidth` base graphics, but you've started with a `ggplot` graphic. The two are not compatible. I suggest you look at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ to see how to customize the legend for this plot. If you want more help with it, you'll need to improve the question by including representative sample data (perhaps `dput(head(meltdf2))`) and what you expect the legend to look like.

Comment: @r2evans thanks - I've posted a working code based on your comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on @r2evans comment above:

The issue was indeed trying to use base graphics commands with a `ggplot` graphic.

To solve this and display the required legend I created a palette vector (`pal`), with names based on the values of the `melt2df$colour` variable in the source dataframe. This vector was included in the plot code as part of a`scale_colour_manual` function. An `aes` function was used within the `geom_point` function to wrap the various aesthetic requirements for the series.

Completed code shown below:

```
pal <- c("High"="red2","Mid"="gold","Low" = "limegreen","NA"= "NA")

#create plot with line and points.
#colour of points based on colour column of meltdf2
ggplot(data = meltdf2, aes(x = Month, y = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(aes(colour = meltdf2$colour, size = 3)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = pal, limits = names(pal)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month" , date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "darkgrey"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```